# Hook Form Alter Specific Node

Tags: nodes, webforms, forms

I want to put a hook to a form on one specific form that I created. Based on Node ID.  The code i currently have is .

Comment: Update own question & put more information. It is uncleare what are you asking.

Comment: The hook that i have will apply to all forms at the moment. I just want it to apply to on particular page. ie., page-node-172 (i get this from fireBug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$form` array contains a `#node` key which has the `nid` attribute. Use that to filter like so:

```
if($form['#node']->nid == 1072) { ... }
```

However, since you ask for `page-node-1072` it sounds like you want to put something in that particular page template, in which case you should use a [process or preprocess function](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) to add or alter variables for the template.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to alter the form on a single page @betherwisser 's answer is the right one. If you want to alter all pages of type webform_client_form, then leave out:

```
if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form') !== FALSE) {}
```

and relpace it with the [function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). In your case:

```
jhumobileform_form_webform_client_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
```

to find out the actual form_id (not sure whether 'webform_client_form' is the right one) install the devel module and activate it, then put dpm($form) in your function:

```
 function jhumobileform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { dpm ($form); //or directly dpm($form_id); }
```

Then, navigate to the site of the form as admin. Within the $form array you can also find the #node key.

Comment: new idea. what if its using a specific theme? is there a way?